# How can i compress this into an EXE without it being seen as a virus? its an updater for my game :/

Tags: batch-file, download, virus, false-positive

I have a batch application which i compress into an exe, unfortunately all virus software detects it as virus due to the fact it has wget and 7zip embeded into the application. anyone know how to solve this?

```
@echo off
title Checking for updates...
if not exist game mkdir game
attrib +h game
del /Q /F game\Online.dat
"%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\Online.dat" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/q205dmocqcfnmg4/Online.txt >nul
set /p online=<game\Online.dat>nul
if %online%==online goto next
goto beg
:next
if not exist "game\ver.dat" echo.0>>game\ver.dat
set /p ver=<game\ver.dat>nul
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("Checking for updates...")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo Checking For Updates...
if exist game\server.dat del /Q /F "game\server.dat"
"%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\server.dat" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/6ecjf7gw2x0lz6i/Update.dat >nul
set /p server=<game\server.dat>nul
if %ver% lss %server% goto update
if %ver% gtr %server% goto update
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("No Updates Found.")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
:beg
game\Game.exe
rd "%myfiles%" /s /q
exit
:update
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("Update Found!")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
cls
del /F /Q "%myfiles%\popup.vbs"
"%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\Updates.vbs" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/qjubq0ypxrtzmx6/Updates.vbs >nul
"%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\Updates.dat" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/j2ks7lsaa2r0kcf/Updates.dat >nul
game\Updates.vbs
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("Updating. Please Wait.")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
rd game /s /q
if not exist game mkdir game
"%myfiles%\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate -O "game\Update.zip" http://dl.dropbox.com/s/0kafa8pmnz6wivn/Update.zip >nul
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("Extracting update. Please Wait.")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\7z.exe" x -o"game" -y "game\Update.zip"
attrib +h game
del /F /Q App\Update.zip
del /F /Q game\ver.dat
echo.%server%>>game\ver.dat
if exist "%myfiles%\voice.vbs" del /Q /F "%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.StrText=("Update Complete.")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.set ObjVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
echo.ObjVoice.Speak StrText>>"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
"%myfiles%\voice.vbs"
goto beg
```

Comment: Are you compressing them into a self extracting archive?  You'll probably find that some AV programs will whine and others won't complain.

Comment: nope it is compiled into an exe in the sense that the batch file and all of its dependancies are run in one location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a program called [`batchtoexe`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat2exe/), I use it and it's never said my programs where viruses.